# Expected Value of a standard normal variable

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, normal-distribution

Suppose that Z has a standard normal distribution...

Evalutate $E[e^z]$

I am having some issues figuring out how to go about this problem.

I understand that $E[e^Z]$ is equal to the integral of $-\infty$ to $\infty$
of $ \dfrac{1}{(2\pi)^.5}e^\dfrac{-z^2}{2}e^z $

I have simplified the integral to $e^{z-z^2/2} $

but I am not sure to go about integrating this. I plugged it into wolframalpha and it gave me $e^.5$ but no explanation.

Comment: The integral you describe is $1$, not $E[z]$.  In general, $E[f(z)]=\frac 1{\sqrt {2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(z)\,e^{-z^2/2}dz$.

Comment: @lulu Ah you are correct thank you, I was missing that crucial part.... But now I am struggling with the integration. I can't see any reasonable way to integrate it by hand

Comment: Why? just complete the square.

Comment: @Gordon Pardon me Gordon, but how would I implement completing the square in this integration? I am struggling with the simplified integration above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align*}
E[e^Z]&=\frac{1}{\sqrt {2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^ze^{-z^2/2}dz\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt {2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-z^2/2 +z}dz\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt {2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(z-1)^2/2 +1/2}dz\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{e}}{\sqrt {2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-u^2/2}du\\
&=\sqrt{e}.
\end{align*}

Comment: How did you make it to that last step? I understand you're supposed to use substitution, but that makes it exp((-u^2)/2) which I am not sure how to integrate

Comment: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp((-u^2)/2) du = 1$, which is the probability $P(-\infty < \xi < \infty)$ for a standard normal $\xi$.

Comment: Ah, okay I did not notice that relation. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Just complete the square in the integral:

$$\exp(-\tfrac{1}{2}z^2 + z) = \exp(-\tfrac{1}{2}(z^2 - 2z)) = \exp(-\tfrac{1}{2}(z^2 - 2z + 1) + \tfrac{1}{2}) = \exp(-\tfrac{1}{2}(z - 1)^2) \sqrt{e}$$

Now you just need to substitute $z - 1 = t$.

Comment: If you substitute t for z-1 then you get exp(-.5(t^2)) ... the derivative of -.5(t^2) is -t, and there is no -t in the integral.. could you please go into a little more detail, I am confused on this portion